# I want to retrieve what lies in the adjacent cell - MS Excel 2007

Tags: excel

My Problem:
 I have a list of Items in one sheet. In one column I have Item Names and in another Column I have the Item Codes which is the adjacent Column. This list is acting as a Items Setup Sheet or table.

Now I have an another sheet within the same workbook wherein I want to issue those items to some person. So what I need is that when I enter the name of item in a column (cell), excel should display the entered Item's code in the adjacent cell.

Example:

Sheet 1:
         A1 = Pencil,      B1 = 1001
         A2 = Notebook,    B2 = 1002
         A3 = Marker,      B3 = 1003

Sheet 2:
         Now In sheet 2, as I enter/select Pencil (for example in Cell D1) then Cell E1 (which is the adjacent cell) should automatically be populated with 1001 which is the item code of the entered/selected item i.e., pencil.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use of a VLOOKUP for this

IN E1

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,Sheet1!$a$2:$b$50,2,0),"")
```

For more info on vlookups... http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/11/19/download-vlookup-cheatsheet/